# Alternate communication types for USB devices

Tags: linux, usb

The general way to communicate with the device via USB is the default control pipe. Is there any other way to communicate with the device?

Comment: What kind of USB device? Depending on the device you have and it's drivers capabilities, you might be able to open it up many ways...also, what is the 'default control pipe'?

Comment: @txtechhelp We have our own device. It is a Arduino and we wanted to use it in our project. It is a special type of message pipe which configures the usb device when it is plugged. (more: http://wiki.osdev.org/Universal_Serial_Bus#Default_Control_Pipe)

Comment: What kind? I've got the 'ethernet' board with a PoE module and 'communicate' with it via the USBSerial adapter (when I'm programming it) but then 'communicate' with it via ethernet when it's in operation. Are you trying to achieve something specific or just wondering if there are other ways to talk to the board?

Comment: @txtechhelp Just generic ways to connect pc with the device using USB. For example any different kind of handlers or protocols.

Comment: Gotchya; I'm not an Arduino expert yet (hence why I'm not answering directly), but to the best of my knowledge the only way to communicate via a PC is through USB because the Arduino's use a serial interface at their base and USB is serial (not including the ethernet/wifi shields you can attach and 'communicate' that way). I'll do some research (because you've piqued my interest) but just a note that you might want to edit your question with more details about your Arduino (board/version/etc) so the other experts can better answer.